# How to automatically login with Python Selenium if there are hidden fields?

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, selenium-chromedriver, hidden

I'm trying to automatically login to a site whose login form is like the following:

```
<form class="login" id="vbLogin" method="post" action="/forum/login.php?do=login">
<input type="hidden" name="do" value="login">
<input type="hidden" name="vb_login_md5password">
<input type="hidden" name="vb_login_md5password_utf">
<input type="hidden" name="s" value="">
<input name="vb_login_username" value="" id="login" type="text" placeholder="Login">
<input name="vb_login_password" value="" class="input" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
<div class="spacerLogin"></div>
<input type="submit" class="submit" value="Login">
<label for="rememberme" class="rememberme">
<input type="checkbox" name="cookieuser" value="1" id="rememberme" checked="checked"> Remember me
</label>
<div class="divider"></div>
<a class="c-header__login__pwdretrieve" href="/forum/login.php?do=lostpw" title="Retrieve lost password">Forgot your password?</a>
<input name="url" type="hidden" value="/product_list/A"></form>
```

In Python/Selenium I sent username/password in the following way but I don't know how to do with hidden fields, and how to apply the submit.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.samplesite.it/forum/login.php?do=login")
username_textbox=driver.find_element_by_id("login")
username_textbox.send_keys("pinco@tin.it")
driver.implicitly_wait(4)
password_textbox=driver.find_element_by_id("password")
password_textbox.send_keys("pallino")
driver.implicitly_wait(4)
login_button=driver.find_element_by_value("Login")
driver.implicitly_wait(4)
login_button.submit()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
driver.get("https://www.samplesite.it/product_list/A")
with open("C:\\mydir\\product_list.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')))
```

I would be very grateful if someone could help me.

Comment: What do you want to do? Actual use case.

Comment: Automatically? Without entering a username/password?

Comment: Entering username password and the hidden fields by python script

Answer (score 0):

The sample HTML you have shared and the code elements you have done doesn't matches exactly.

However If the above HTML correct then to handle dynamic elements Induce
`WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`()

**Code**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.samplesite.it/forum/login.php?do=login")
username_textbox=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,"vb_login_username")))
username_textbox.send_keys("pinco@tin.it")
password_textbox=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,"vb_login_password")))
password_textbox.send_keys("pallino")
login_button=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input.submit[value='Login']")))
login_button.click()
```

Comment: Thank you, @Kunduk, you were right, my parameters in find_element_by_id were wrong. Anyway I used your code. It writes correctly the username field but the password field is left empty. Probably because I didn't manage the hidden fields in the beginnings of the form.